# Программа для удаленного просмотра экрана

Tags: java, библиотеки

Есть задание: разработать приложение для удаленного просмотра экрана другого устройства.
Желательный язык для реализации задачи: *Java*.
Копал в сторону библиотеки *Xuggle*, но ничего путного не вышло.
Поделитесь библиотекой и/или видео/документацией/сайтом, где описано создание похожего приложения и т.д.

Comment: какого устройства? на андроид? или ПК?

Comment: Разработка идет под ПК, ОС Windows

Comment: Вам надо посмотреть на WinApi. Так как средствам самой Java посмотреть экран нельзя, а через WinApi можно и можно вызвать методы WinApi из Java. Но лучше взять другой язык, тот что является родным (native) для Windows.